# Adding object pair to a single object and removing it when needed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My task is to add or remove object pair to an single object on particular user action;

exmaple:

```
const myObj = {};

considr there is 3 buttons, button1, button2, button3 and So when user perform a action (pressing a button1), we need to add {key:'1'} to above obj and the output should be as follows,

myObj = {key: '1'};

second & third button action;

myObj = {key: '1', key: '2', key: '3'}.....

And when use rehits the button1 we need to remove the respective and the output should be as follows,

myObj = {key: '2', key: '3'}
```

How to perform this ? Actually the datas are different so just used key concept for demonstration ! Main problem is how to add to single object and how to remove that on action !

I tried,

```
      var myArray  = {};
      myArray.push(data);
      this.setState({ selected_sort : [...selected_sort, myArray] })
```

But it doesnt add on single object, it keeps on adding new object with duplicates !

I even tried lodash,

```
_.merge(receivedData, myObj)
```

But no use, please guide

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with objects, you can't use the same name for each key. It's like a hash-map. Every key should be with a unique name.

For each button, give a different key name, such as {button1: '1'}

Our object will look like this:

```
var myObjs = {};
```

When Clicking on one of the buttons, we will use some function to insert the relevant button object as I mentioned earlier.

```
buttonClicked(buttonName, buttonValue) {
 myObjs = {
  ...myObjs,
  [buttonName]: buttonValue
 }
}
```

Now, if you want to remove the button object if it already exists in myObjs, so you can use delete:

```
buttonClicked(buttonName, buttonValue) {
 if(myObjs[buttonName]) {
  delete myObjs[buttonName];
  return;
 }
 myObjs = {
  ...myObjs,
  [buttonName]: buttonValue
 }
}
```

Is this what you looking for?